# How to Find Keypoints after doing Difference of Gaussian Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have already write a code of finding DIfference of Gaussian Filter now please tell me how to find keypoints from that filtered image based on maxima and minima

### Difference of Gaussian Filter Program

```
clc;

X=imread('DSC00963.JPG');

k = 10;
sigma1 =  0.5;
sigma2 = sigma1*k;

hsize = [3,3];

h1 = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma1);
h1 = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma2);

gauss1 = imfilter(img,h1,'replicate');
gauss2 = imfilter(img,h2,'replicate');

dogImg = gauss1 - gauss2;

imshow(dogImg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can just compare every pixel with shifted images. Below finds 4-neighbor maxima.

```
mask = dogImg > dogImg([1, 1:end-1], :) & ...
       dogImg > dogImg([2:end, end], :) & ...
       dogImg > dogImg(:, [1, 1:end-1]) & ...
       dogImg > dogImg(:, [2:end, end]);
[y, x] = find(mask);
```